# A different way reference rows of data in Python from csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Is there a way to reference rows of data from a csv brought into Python, using iterators? What I would like to do is instead of this code:

```
with open('some.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    row1 = next(data)
    row2 = next(data)
    row3 = next(data)
    row4 = next(data)
    row5 = next(data)
```

This code works fine, but I would like to have it as something like the code below:

```
with open('some.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    for i in data:
        row[i] = next(data)
```

I want to do this because I use this in code that reorganizes data that is stored in very long rows. There are often a varying number of rows in each csv, so having a way for the code to discover on its own how many rows there are would be nice rather than just creating what are hopefully enough rowN's.

Comment: Take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply convert the iterator returned by `csv.reader` into a list so that the rows become indexable:

```
with open('some.csv') as f:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Comment: Wow that was so simple why didnt I think of that. Each row is a list within a list. Thank you!